# Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial: Rspec's "Expected response to be a redirect to ..." is wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

In Michael Hartl's (wonderful) Rails Tutorial I'm getting an unexpected Rspec test failure of the form:

> "Expected response to be a redirect to
>   <http://test.host/signin> but was a
>   redirect to
>   <http://test.host/signin?notice=Please+sign+in+to+access+this+page.>."

(Find this in Section 10.3.) So, from the very error, you can se that the server is redirecting to the appropriate page except that there is an additional notice to "Please sign in".  The code of the test looks like this:

```
describe "GET 'index'" do

describe "for non-signed-in users" do
  it "should deny access" do
    get :index
    response.should redirect_to(signin_path)
    flash[:notice].should =~ /sign in/i
  end
end

...
```

Am I doing something wrong here?  How best should I fix this?

---

**Update:**

If I change the code to

```
response.should redirect_to('http://test.host/signin?notice=Please+sign+in+to+access+this+page.')
```

then I get and actual Ruby error

> Failure/Error: flash[:notice].should
>   =~ /sign in/i
>        expected: /sign in/i,
>             got: nil (using =~)

---

**Resolution**

The problem was an omitted comma in my deny_access function:

```
redirect_to signin_path :notice => "Please sign in to access this page."
```

should have been

```
redirect_to signin_path, :notice => "Please sign in to access this page."
```

This fixed it.  Now, the side affect of this fix was interesting wasn't it?  Does this imply that `signin_path` is itself a function that can take a hash or arguments to be appended to the end of the path?  Weird, wild, and wonderful.

Comment: Ahh! Yep, you can pass arguments into named routes. See http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Routing.html

Comment: This is the gotcha of parentheses-less code. Add parentheses and the error is much easier to spot, IMHO.

Comment: @zetetic - Yes, this is once concern I have been mulling over.  Before I learned Ruby, I learned Python wherein there is alway just *one* way to do things right (e.g. you *have to* us parens; there is no such supurfluous construct as `unless`), and the code is always consistent.  No matter who wrote it, it looks the same.  Ruby, on the other hand, let's you do whatever you feel best doing - which is "fun".  I guess there's something to be said for both aesthetics.

Comment: @JohnBerryman Answers should be answers, not edits to the question. And yes, `signin_path` is a method generated by Rails. It *may* take arguments, whether or not they're used depends on the particular route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do your authentication methods look like? I haven't seen the flash notice added to the query string like that before :/ It leads me to believe your methods might be incorrect. It should be something like:

```
def deny_access
  redirect_to signin_path, :notice => "Please sign in to access this page."
end
```

OR

```
def deny_access
  flash[:notice] = "Please sign in to access this page."
  redirect_to signin_path
end
```

Comment: good call, you drew my attention to the problem... see update